# Trigger buttons in bootstrap modal body generated from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I'm generating a modal body form an ajax call which consists of several buttons with specific ids. Below is the code.

```
$('.btn-detail').on( "click", function(e) {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");

    e.preventDefault();

    $('.modal-body').load('/product/'+id+'/show-detail', function(){
        $('#detail').modal({ show:true });
    });
});
```

Here is content a the modal

```
<div>
    <button id="btn-a">Do Something</button>
    <button id="btn-b">Do Something Else</button>
</div>
```

I have initiated the buttons function in the same view,

```
$('#btn-a').click(function(){
    //do something
});

$('#btn-b').click(function(){
    //do something else
});
```

I've been reading about jQuery event handler but don't know how to apply to this condition.

Comment: What doesn't work ? Not sure what you are asking please elaborate ..

Comment: I'v tried this  $('.btn-detail').on( "click", "#btn-a", function(e)...
Then the function do nothing instead of loading the content. If i do not add the #btn-a handler, it just loading fine but the button didn't function.

Comment: In your code `id="btn-a"` is id and you are using class selector i.e : `$('.btn-a')..` ?

Comment: Swati, it typo error..it's an id actually. Thanks, I'm editing my question.

Comment: Try using it like this `$('.modal-body').on('click', '#btn-a', function(){..` or `$(document).on('click',  '#btn-a', function(){.`

Comment: @Swati, thanks, that's just simply works!